# How to bind Element to a fragment under a different name ? [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, fragment, sapui5

as the title states, i want to to bind certain `model` Elements to the `Fragment` under different `names`.

**Model:**

```
modelExample = {
  0:{"Name": "Example", Number:13}
}

as "modelExample" in .setModel
```

**Fragment:**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <ResponsivePopover contentWidth="90%" contentHeight="90%" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" placement="Right">
        <content>
            <Text text="{modelExample&gt;/Generic}"/>
        </content>
    </ResponsivePopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Would like to bind `Number` attribute to the `Fragment`, but under a different name, 'Generic'

**Normal Process:**

```
this._oPopover.bindElement("modelExample", "/Number");
```

**Issue:** It binds it under `/Number` attribute name.

**Question:** How to bind an `model` `attribute` to a `fragment` under a different `attribute name`

Comment: This is not possible and why should it? Can explain why the fragment has to use another name? Furthermore Number is not really a good name as it is a JavaScript keyword.

Comment: Hey @matbtt, `Number` is used as an example `attribute`, to make an point, it isn't really meant to showcase a real example. Issue is: There is already an `fragment` that is already in use, that is structuarally exactly what i want to represent with this but with  different names for attributes, thus, reusing exact same fragment is what i want.